# Use variable for URL in powershell BITS transfer

Tags: powershell

I have the following in a powershell script:

```
$src_url = "http://my_server/my_file.zip"
if (!(Test-Path $src_zip))
{
    "Downloading $src_url"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source "$src_url" -Destination .\$src_zip
}
```

The output of which is

```
Downloading http://my_server/my_file.zip
Start-BitsTransfer : The server name or address could not be resolved
At C:\foo.ps1:18 char:5
+     Start-BitsTransfer -Source "$src_url" -Destination .\$src_zip
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferComma
   nd
```

I have tried with, without double and single quotes around the URL. However if I type the URL out directly the name is resolved correctly. What should I do to expand `$src_url`?

Comment: It should expand fine like this only. Try adding -Verbose switch and inspect $Error variable.

Comment: Also, what happens if you hard code URL? If it doesn’t work, problem is not in variable expansion. Start-Bitstransfer -Source “http://my_server/my_file.zip”  -Dest c:\temp

Comment: It works when I hardcode the URL. -Verbose isn't giving me any extra information.

Comment: It turns out I screwed up the URL at some point. So it wasn't an expansion issue after-all.

Comment: Okay, from error you pasted, it may due to destination. Try to use full path in it. $src_zip = "C:\temp\abc.zip" please see if the destination file needs to be removed or u you can use force parameter.

Comment: @zerocool18, If you will post an answer I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it works with hard-coding URL, the source variable should expand correctly in your syntax.

And from error you pasted, it may due to destination path resolution. Try to use full path in it. Example,

```
$src_zip = "C:\temp\abc.zip"
```

Please see if the destination file needs to be removed or you can use force parameter.

Comment: Thanks for edit. I couldn’t format with code block from mobile.